# Why cant curl/OpenSSL fetch a website that chrome+firefox can?

Tags: curl, https, openssl

Both in my program (which uses OpenSSL) and curl, I cannot fetch a website:

```
$ curl -v https://registration.experient-inc.com/HTMLProduction/ShowCES131/ConfirmationImages/CES131_Header.JPG
* About to connect() to registration.experient-inc.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 12.153.51.94...
* connected
* Connected to registration.experient-inc.com (12.153.51.94) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /usr/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to registration.experient-inc.com:443
* Closing connection #0
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to registration.experient-inc.com:443
```

As per a different question I will post what happens with a direct openssl call:

```
$ openssl s_client -host 12.153.51.94 -port 443
CONNECTED(00000003)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

Any idea of why this is happening/how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently that web server does not support SSLv2 at all. I.e. it doesnt even support the SSLv2 hello. Forcing curl or OpenSSL to use SSLv3+ results in a working query.